# can't install module databas-auto in odoo 11

Tags: docker, odoo

when i try to install module for backup database odoo 11: https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/auto_backup/, i use postgres 10,and ubuntu 18.04 LTS i have this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 832, in convert_csv_import
    raise Exception(_('Module loading %s failed: file %s could not be processed:\n %s') % (module, fname, warning_msg))
Exception: Module loading auto_backup failed: file auto_backup/security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:
 No matching record found for external id 'model_db_backup' in field 'Object'
Missing required value for the field 'Object' (model_id)
No matching record found for external id 'model_db_backup' in field 'Object'
Missing required value for the field 'Object' (model_id)
```